# Blender Geometry Nodes Collection instances scale

Tags: geometry-nodes, geometry, procedural, collections

I´m trying to find a way to scale the proximity geometry mask with collection objects. I would scale the object inside the collection and the mask would always be 2x the size of the object scaled (while the mask from the rest of the obj in the collection would stay the same), right now is a constant value (ex: mask is always plus .2 bigger than the object).

When I scale the value in the map range node (from min) it does exactly what I want, but is equal to all objects in the collection. I tried to get the instance scale of the instances in the collection, tried bounding box min max point of each individual instance, all those give the right value but when I plug into to the map range (from min) to adapt to each instance it goes to 0.

Img. 1 default
Img. 2 obj scaled but the mask didn´t (not plugin into map range from min)
Img. 3 used instanced scale into the map range but it goes to 0 even tho a value exists

Could anyone help me with this?

[image]

[image]

[image]